# How to use external js file?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to move a js script from the html file to an external js file and I can't get it to work.The js script works fine when in the html file but when I try to use it from an external js file it does not work.I've looked up how to import external js file and I think I'm doing it right but my script is not working.What am I doing wrong?

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NAVBAR</title>
    <meta name="description" content="NAVBAR - A responsive nav manu." />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function(){

            $('.m_btn').click( function(){

                $('.menu').stop().slideToggle();

            });

        });
    </script>
    -->
</head>

<body>
    <header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">NAVBAR</div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="m_btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </a>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>

    <main>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </main> 

    <footer>
        <p>NAVBAR 2018</p>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="navbar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The js:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('m_btn').click( function() {

        $('.menu').stop().slideToggle();

    });

});
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

header {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
   float: right;
}

.menu ul {

}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
    color: #2d2d2d;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #d2d2d2;
    text-decoration: none ;
}

.m_btn {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
}

.m_btn span {
    background: #2d2d2d;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Mobile */
@media only screen and ( max-width: 599px ) {
    .m_btn {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu {
        display: none; 
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 1px;
    }

    .menu ul li {
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
        float: none;
    }
}

/* Desktop */
@media only screen and ( min-width: 600px ) {
    .m_btn {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu {
        display: block !important;
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please explicitly explain what "isn't working right".  What is it supposed to do?  What is it doing?  Have you opened your developer tools and looked for any errors?  What are they?  Are you getting 404s?

Comment: The menu toggle @zero298

Comment: Please also add your CSS file

Comment: Open your dev console (ctrl+shift+k in Firefox). are you seeing a 404 for navbar.js? I'm assuming you are running this locally, not on a server. If that's the case, `/navbar.js` isn't going to be found since that's an absolute path. Removing the slash would allow you to view it locally.

Comment: The console does give an error: Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///navbar.js”.

Comment: I also removed the slash before navbar.js and the console doesn't throw error anymore but script still not working.

Comment: There is a typo in js file,  `$('m.btn')` instead of  `$('m_btn')`

Comment: Thanks @RamY! I fixed the typo. Script still not working though.

Comment: Also Added the CSS @zero298

Comment: I'll be leaving for work in an hour and won't be able to reply to any comments or answers probably until later tomorrow.I do appreciate everyone's help and will get back with everyone as soon as I can. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check typo $('m.btn')...
2) Put your scripts before closing body tag.
3) If you run your site locally - delete / before navbar.js in the path.
Navbar.js must be in the same directory with your index.html file.
This must help.

Comment: Edit your question with instructions I gave to you, so we can replicate and run the site.

Comment: I updated the question with your instructions, let me know if you replicate this and it works.

Comment: There's still no dot  "." before $('.m_btn') in your external js file below document ready function. Check inserted js and external.

Comment: Okay that was the issue! I fixed the m.btn typo and thought that was what u were referring to but that was the issue.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the browser is not able to load the script at all, probably because it cannot find it.  I would suggest ensuring the filename is spelled exactly the same as the file.  If it is in the same directory, try removing the first slash.  Also, open up the web terminal (CTRL + SHIFT + I on most browsers) and see what the console says in terms of errors.

Comment: Optionally if you don't have octo-arms you can press `f12`